# AllegroGraph taking up fill disk space

Tags: memory-management, cpu-usage, allegrograph

We have AllegroGraph 4.9 running, we have added about a billion triples to the repository. We reached the full capacity of disk space and so we stopped the loading and doubled the disk(80G to 200G), now even that disk space is full though we have not added any extra triples.

Also, the memory is fully utilized which was also doubled from initial 16G to 32G when no queries are running. And, while running of some queries the CPU Utilization goes 100% and we dont even get the response back.

First, I want to know what could be the reason of increase in disk space and memory. Then, dwell into the second part of high CPU utilization while running of queries.

Any suggestions on this issue ?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I've been using AllegroGraph's LLM demos and even though I have a ton of space as far as my triple limit (my license is for 700M triples and I have around 1M) I'm still getting errors when I create a new repository or try to use an existing one such as: "Creating repository failed:
When allocating the string table failed to create shared memory segment of size 134,225,920, message: "insufficient shared memory space available" I'm going to email help but I always like to try and figure things out myself first. Interested if you made any progress here.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend emailing support@franz.com.